# Problems with a makefile and mixed Fortran and Fortran 90 code

Tags: makefile, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to update some old Fortran code and I want to use a makefile to build it.  Right now, my makefile looks like

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -O2

HDRS = global.h param.h coor.h
SRCS = xxx.f yyy.f zzz.f newstuff.f90 main.f
OBJS = $(SRCS:.f=.o)
OBJS := $(OBJS:.f90=.o)

runit: $(OBJS)
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $^

xxx.o yyy.o main.o : global.h
yyy.o zzz.o: coor.h
xxx.o yyy.o zzz.o main.o : param.h
xxx.o main.o : newstuff.o

clean:
        rm runit *.o *.mod

.SUFFIXES: .f .f90 .o

.f.o:
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<
.f90.o:
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<
```

I have two questions.  First, I edit newstuff.f90 and then issue `make newstuff.o`, expecting a new `newstuff.o`.  Instead, I get the message that newstuff.o is up to date.  This doesn't happen with any of the other source codes.  What do I have to do to convince make that newstuff.o is indeed out of date?

Second, trying to hack a fix, I inserted the line (not shown above): `newstuff.o : newstuff.f90`.  But with that line in the makefile, make returns

```
m2c    -o mpi_wrapper.o mpi_wrapper.mod
make: m2c: No such file or directory
```

Why does make go for this other utility m2c, whatever that is?  How do I convince it to use gfortran?  Thanks.

Comment: What the hell is mixed Fortran and Fortran 90? BTW `.f90` does NOT mean it is Fortran 90 (unfortunately).

Comment: @Vladimir F Some Fortran 77 code and some new Fortran 90 code.  Make seems to be treating the two differently.  The new code uses modules, the old does not.  That seems to be the difference as far as make is concerned.

Comment: m2c is a Modula compiler. Make thinks .mod is a Modula source code. You must tell make to ignore `.mod` files.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Do you have any other files named `newstuff*` lying around? And what version of Make are you using (`make -v`)?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

there is a default rule treating mod files as Modula files. You can disable this rule by adding this following line followed by a blank line to your Makefile:

`%.o : %.mod`